# How do I copy subfolders into another location

Tags: python, synchronization, backup

I'm making a program to back up files and folders to a destination.
The problem I'm currently facing is if I have a folder inside a folder and so on, with files in between them, I can't Sync them at the destination.

e.g.:

The source contains folder 1 and file 2. Folder 1 contains folder 2, folder 2 contains folder 3 and files etc...

The backup only contains folder 1 and file 2.

If the backup doesn't exist I simply use: `shutil.copytree(path, path_backup)`, but in the case, I need to sync I can't get the files and folders or at least I'm not seeing a way to do it. I have walked the directory with `for path, dir, files in os.walk(directory)` and even used what someone suggest in another post:

```
def walk_folder(target_path, path_backup): 
    for files in os.scandir(target_path):
        if os.path.isfile(files):
           file_name = os.path.abspath(files)
           print(file_name)
           os.makedirs(path_backup)
        elif os.path.isdir(files):
           walk_folder(files, path_backup)
```

Is there a way to make the directories in the backup folder from the ground up and then add the info alongside or is the only way to just delete the whole folder and use `shutil.copytree(path, path_backup)`.
With makedirs, all it does is say it can't create because the folder already exists, this is understandable as it's trying to write in the Source folder and not in the backup. Is there a way to make the path to replace Source for backup?
If any more code is needed feel free to ask!

Comment: You could use [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) to remove complete directory/file trees. Beyond that you would need to be more specific about what syncing involves here (e.g. deleting files/directories in the backup path if they don't exist in original anymore ...?)

Comment: I have been able to finish it... many tears were shed haha. But yes, by syncing I mean, if any alteration was done to a file it would be synced to the backup folder. Also any deletion or creating wouldn't be sync but rather added/deleted